# histogram: shortcut for if statements and formatting

Tags: java, format, histogram

My program reads any number of integers from a file and then prints a histogram bar-chart for all integers between 1 and 100.
The code works, and I tried already to make it shorter with all possible formatting, but then my code stopped working. So this long version is the only version working right now. 
So my question is only out of curiosity, if there is a shorter way for my if statements and for the printing of the histogram.
Note: not all integers in the file are neccesarily in the interval [1-100]

```
    Create an object representing a file
    File file = new File("path");
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file);

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int total=0;
    while (fileScan.hasNext()){
        total++;
            list.add(fileScan.nextInt());
    }
    int [] counter = new int [10];
    for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++){
        if (list.get(i) >=1 && list.get(i)<=10){
            counter[0]++;
        }
        if (list.get(i) >10 && list.get(i)<=20){
            counter[1]++;
        }
        if (list.get(i) >20 && list.get(i)<=30){
            counter[2]++;
        }
        if (list.get(i) >30 && list.get(i)<=40){
            counter[3]++;
        }
        if (list.get(i) >40 && list.get(i)<=50){
            counter[4]++;
        }
        if (list.get(i) >50 && list.get(i)<=60){
            counter[5]++;
        }
        if (list.get(i) >60 && list.get(i)<=70){
            counter[6]++;
        }
        if (list.get(i) >70 && list.get(i)<=80){
            counter[7]++;
        }
        if (list.get(i) >80 && list.get(i)<=90){
            counter[8]++;
        }
        if (list.get(i) >90 && list.get(i)<=100){
            counter[9]++;
        }
    }
    int valueTotal=0;
    for (int j=0; j<counter.length; j++){
        valueTotal += counter[j];
    }
    System.out.print("Reading integers from file: "+file);
    System.out.print("\nNumber of integers in the interval [1,100]: "+valueTotal);
    System.out.print("\nOthers: "+(total-valueTotal));
    System.out.print("\nHistogram\n");  
    System.out.print("1 - 10  | ");
    display(counter[0]);
    System.out.print("\n11 - 20 | ");
    display(counter[1]);
    System.out.print("\n21 - 30 | ");
    display(counter[2]);
    System.out.print("\n31 - 40 | ");
    display(counter[3]);
    System.out.print("\n41 - 50 | ");
    display(counter[4]);
    System.out.print("\n51 - 60 | ");
    display(counter[5]);
    System.out.print("\n61 - 70 | ");
    display(counter[6]);
    System.out.print("\n71 - 80 | ");
    display(counter[7]);
    System.out.print("\n81 - 90 | ");
    display(counter[8]);
    System.out.print("\n91 - 100| ");
    display(counter[9]);
    }
    public static void display(int n){
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    }
}
```

my output:

```
   Reading integers from file: ....txt
   Number of integers in the interval [1,100]: 18
   Others: 4
   Histogram
   1 - 10  | ******
   11 - 20 | *
   21 - 30 | ***
   31 - 40 | 
   41 - 50 | *
   51 - 60 | *
   61 - 70 | *
   71 - 80 | ***
   81 - 90 | *
   91 - 100| *
```

Comment: You must always have bins (`counter` elements) for values out of range on both ends unless you can _guarantee_ the bin calculation never produces an out of range bin number.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `counter[(list.get(i) - 1) / 10]++;` or something similar should be able to replace all those if statements.

Edit: given your changed requirements, you will need to first test that the index is not out of bounds:

```
int index = (list.get(i) - 1 ) / 10;
if (index >= 0 || index < counter.length) {
    counter[index]++;
} else {
    // not sure if you need to do something for index out of bounds
}
```

Comment: this gives me also an exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13   as hotzst already mentioned, I forgot to write that the program also counts integers not in the Intervall [1, 100]

Comment: @Bruthzilla: then you'd best test for that on the lines before using it as an index.

Answer (score 1):

As you collect the values in segments of size 10, you could use `/` (integer division) to calculate the index:

```
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    int value = Math.min(list.get(i), 100);
    int index = value / 10 - 1;
    counter[index]++;
}
```

Comment: that generated an exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13

Comment: Only if the value you input is larger than `100` which can be handled easily, and the index must be adjusted like in @Hovercraft Full Of Eels example. In addition it would be good practice to initialize the `counter` array beforehand.

Comment: oh, that's right. I didn't state that in my post. Because the program reads any number of integers, and counts the integers which are between 1 - 100 and it counts also the integers which are not in this Intervall. You can only see it in the output. But I will edit this right away.

Answer (score -2):

`counter[(list.get(i) - 1) / 10]++;` seems the most concise. You could also use a [switch statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement) in your for-loop to get rid of the ifs and put everything in the same code block. Also, storing the element at the i-th index saves you a lot of repeated `get`ting

EDIT: Original code wasn't consistent with Java syntax. Here's the updated version. The expression inside `switch` is the key:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++){
  int x = lst.get(i);
  switch((x-1)/10){
    case 1: counter[0]++;
    case 2: counter[1]++;
    case 3: counter[2]++;
    case 4: counter[3]++;
    case 5: counter[4]++;
    case 6: counter[5]++;
    case 7: counter[6]++;
    case 8: counter[7]++;
    case 9: counter[8]++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that valid Java? And are you sure? Have you tested it?